# Positive operator on Hilbert space 3

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, linear-transformations

Can someone explain me how to solve the following;

Considering Hilbert space $H$, I am supposed to prove that a positive operator $T \in B(H)$ is bijective if and only if $T-\epsilon I $ is positive-definite for some $\epsilon >0.$

Here, $B(H)$ is the space of all continuous oeprators on $H$.

I am a bit out of functional analysis stuff, but need this in further results.

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Comment: what happens if $T=Id$ and $\epsilon=1$ ?

Comment: By one definition, the zero operator is not positive-definite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true as it is stated. Let's suppose $H=\mathbb C^n$ for some $n$, $T\in B(H)$ is positive, and $Tx=\lambda x$ for some $\lambda\geq0$ and $x\in H$ non-zero.  Then
$\langle Tx,x\rangle=\lambda\langle x,x\rangle$, so if $\varepsilon>\lambda\geq0$ we have $\langle (T-\varepsilon I)x,x\rangle<0$, and therefore $T-\varepsilon I$ is not positive.

**EDIT**

If $T\in B(H)$ is positive, and $T- \varepsilon I$ is positive for some $\varepsilon>0$, then $\sigma(T-\varepsilon I)\subset[0,\infty)$ where $\sigma(S)$ denotes the spectrum of $S\in B(H)$.  Thus $\sigma(T)\subset[\varepsilon,\infty)$, so $0\notin\sigma(T)$ and therefore $T$ is invertible.

If $T\in B(H)$ is positive, and $T$ is invertible, then $\sigma(T)\subset(0,\infty)$.  But $\sigma(T)$ is compact (in particular closed), so $\sigma(T)\subset[\varepsilon,\infty)$ for some $\varepsilon>0$. Hence $\sigma(T-\varepsilon I)\subset[0,\infty)$, and thus $T-\varepsilon I$ is positive.

Comment: I have just edited the question. It is not for any, but for some $\epsilon$. @Aweygan

Comment: Alright I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I gave some hints to help you.  If you want some more information, let me know and I'll edit some more.

Comment: Can you just explain how does the last sentence (compactness of spectrum) give the answer?

Comment: Does that help?

Comment: As a matter of fact, I would like to get some more informations, hints don't help as much as I thought they will